# How do I create a jquery vertical scroll of div contents on hover?

Tags: jquery

How do I create a jquery-powered vertical scroll of div contents on hover, not on click?

Check out this [example](http://www.alfadm.sk/en/index.html). Try hovering the rightbar under the flags. It will start scrolling the content the way your mouse hovers.

I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can't exactly just *give* you the answer to this, but as a hint you would have to use the `mousemove` event and detect where, within the panel, the mouse is. Set `overflow: hidden;` and move a relative speed to how close the mouse is to the edge. I'd recommend using two divs - one outer div to set the boundaries (detect mousemove on this div) and then the other one absolutely positioned.

It would be something like this:

HTML:

```
<div id='outer'>
    <div id='inner'>
        <p>Overflowing content here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#outer {
    height: 200px;
    width: 150px;
    position: relative;
}

#inner {
    position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; overflow: hidden;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#outer").mousemove(function(e) {
        //Refer to [here][1] to get position of mouse within element.
        //Get position of mouse within the element, if it is at the top then compare how close it is to 0, if it is at the bottom then compare how close it is to 200px (or whatever you set as the height of the outer container). Slide inner container as appropriate.
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

look at this I have fixed someone's code: http://jsfiddle.net/n3Q9j/5/

Comment: very nice solution, but the animation wasn't smooth in my case, so I added a flag to singal it's in the middle of a cycle

Comment: @MosheShaham Could you share what you did exactly?  I'm getting a similar lack of smoothness, but this is only my second attempt at JQuery so I don't know how to solve it.