# Smoothing out a JQuery scroll animation from mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation

I've got a JQuery scroll animation (derived from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8871770/1418688) to a question that almost perfectly met my needs), and it's working.  I'm trying to get a side-scroll of icons when the user hovers over the edges of a row, sort of like how Netflix organizes its browser main page with the different movie posters.

But much like the commenter, I'm having some very slow, ugly choppiness with the animation.  Specifically, when the mouse hovers at the edges to start the animation it is very choppy, but when the mouse then leaves the `div` entirely the animation smooths out.  Return the mouse to the area, though, and it gets choppy again.

Here's my code, adapted with few changes from that answer above...

```
$(".scroller").mousemove(function(e){
    var h = $('#innerscroller').width()+13;
    var offset = $($(this)).offset();
    var position = (e.pageX-offset.left)/$(this).width();

    if(position < 0.10) {
        $(this).stop().animate({ scrollLeft: 0 }, 5000);
        $(".status").html('Percentage1:' + position.toFixed(2) + ' lefting');
    }
    else if(position > 0.90) {
        $(this).stop().animate({ scrollLeft: h }, 5000);
        $(".status").html('Percentage3:' + position.toFixed(2) + ' righting');
    } else {
        $(this).stop();
        $(".status").html('Percentage2:' + position.toFixed(2));
    }
});
```

And the HTML...

```
<div class="scroller" style="width:680px; overflow-x:auto; overflow:hidden; white-space:nowrap; background-color:blue">
    <div id="innerscroller" style="width:auto;">
        // Row of icons here.
    </div>
</div>
```

I am a total JQuery noob, this is only the second time I've ever even touched it.  Can someone tell me how I might smooth out the animation so it's a nice elegant scroll to the side?

And for bonus points, I'd like it to stop entirely when the mouse leaves the `scroller` div, so they don't end up with ten scrolling rows whenever they move their mouse across the screen.

**UPDATE:** I noticed a bit of a clue, for anyone who could diagnose the problem: it scrolls normally as long as my mouse is moving.  If I keep my mouse within the hover area and just move it around, it scrolls perfectly. It's only when my mouse stops that it starts to chug along slowly.  Any ideas?

**UPDATE 2:** I've made a [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Uy7Hs/) to illustrate what I'm experiencing.  Hovering over the area does begin the scroll, but you have to hover over the area and then move your mouse away to get it to be anything but choppy and awkward.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just try out the jQuery Easing plugin - http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/

Include the file and choose any easing type you like.